# Facebook iOS SDK Disable auto log app events

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

According to the documentation for Facebooks iOS SDK, in order to turn off automatic events (specifically looking to turn off APP INSTALL), you need to set the following plist flag to false.

```
FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled
```

I've also verify on startup that the value of

```
Settings.shared.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = false
```

Documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#auto-events

However, when I monitor network traffic,  I'm seeing the graph api being called with the MOBILE_INSTALL event.

```
URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/appid/activities
{
  "include_headers": "false",
  "advertiser_id_collection_enabled": "1",
  "advertiser_id": "REMOVED",
  "application_tracking_enabled": "1",
  "event": "MOBILE_APP_INSTALL",
  "ud": "{}",
  "sdk": "ios",
  "format": "json",
  "extinfo": "[\"i2\",\"REMOVED\",\"3994\",\"3.1.20\",\"16.2\",\"iPhone15,3\",\"en_US\",\"EDT\",\"T-Mobile\",430,932,\"3.00\",6,119,21,\"America\\/New_York\"]",
  "install_timestamp": "1696449290",
  "url_schemes": "[\"REMOVED\",\"REMOVED\",\"REMOVED\",\"REMOVED\"]",
  "advertiser_tracking_enabled": "1",
  "access_token": "REMOVED",
  "anon_id": "REMOVED"
}
```

Am I missing something to stop that event from being sent automatically.  I'm using using iOS facebook SDK 15.1.0.